# Python: Combination with one criteria

Tags: python, combinations

i need combination list like

```
000002
000003
000004
000006
000007
000008
000009
000012
......
999998
999999
```

But i don't need 0 and 1 and the end of number, how i can do it? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were *supposed* to finish before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your list consists of strings. Have you tried using int()? For example `int('0001')` returns 1, after stripping out the leading 0s.

If you have a long list, you could try using a list comprehension as follows. For example, if a = ['001', '002', '003'], then `b = [int(x) for x in a]`, would make b = [1, 2, 3].